# GWT Disappearing Charts Issue

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

I have several content panels, which I switch between, and several of them have charts. (ie. they use the google visualization api).

The problem is that the first time you view a panel the chart displays, but then when you switch back to it later the chart does not display.  It just shows up as blank.

The solution I have currently is to just recreate the chart and set its widget to the correct location in the grid I am using.  However, this seems like overkill...

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It seems related to this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationFAQ#I_removed_a_VisualizationWidget_from_a_Panel.__When_I_added_it_b

(except the charts aren't being detached directly, but rather their grandparent pane is detached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's somehow a known problem.
Currently with google chart tools in GWT you have to re-create the charts when they are detached or any parent container element is detached.
There is no workaround AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

its been a known bug in charts for years. My workaround was to `addAttachHandler` and automatically redraw the chart whenever an attach event is fired.